# How i can get the difference of closest two date in two table join in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having two tables in which 
 table1

```
     activity_timestamp    | activity 
                           |    
 2016-12-23 13:53:47.608561| details viewed
 2017-01-09 14:15:52.570397| details viewed
 2016-12-27 16:06:39.138994| details viewed
 2016-12-24 21:09:56.159436| details viewed
```

table2

```
     activity_timestamp    | activity 
                           |    
 2016-12-23 13:54:47.608561| reading
 2017-01-09 14:17:52.570397| reading
 2016-12-27 16:10:39.138994| reading
 2016-12-24 21:012:56.159436| reading
```

I have to calculate the time between these two activity means reading and detail viewed
Result table

```
    timediff (minutes)

        1
        2
        4 
        3
```

These are two tables I have to do the join on these table with condition 
difference between two activity_timestamp is less than 20 min then only that record will be added in final table 
for that I have writen this query

```
select DATE_PART('minutes', a1.activity_timestamp- b.activity_timestamp), 
    a1.activity_timestamp, b.activity_timestamp 
from table a1 LEFT JOIN table2 b 
   ON(DATE_PART('minutes', (a1.activity_timestamp - b.activity_timestamp))< 20  
      and (a1.activity_timestamp>b.activity_timestamp)) 
order by b.activity_timestamp;
```

But i'm getting the result which is seems to be ambiguous
what i can do to get the join which will return me the the record which having only 20 min difference

Comment: If you only have timestamps you can't have "the record" since there may be unlimited amount of records. Please add an explanation of the result you want and the result you know get

Comment: Is a activity always after b activity?

Comment: yes in first table their will be records those are 5-10 min earlier  than second record

Answer (score 1):

```
with
  table1(activity_timestamp, activity) as (
    values
      ('2016-12-23 13:53:47.608561'::timestamp, 'details viewed'),
      ('2017-01-09 14:15:52.570397', 'details viewed'),
      ('2016-12-27 16:06:39.138994', 'details viewed'),
      ('2016-12-24 21:09:56.159436', 'details viewed')),
  table2(activity_timestamp, activity) as (
    values
      ('2016-12-23 13:54:47.608561'::timestamp, 'reading'),
      ('2017-01-09 14:17:52.570397', 'reading'),
      ('2016-12-27 16:10:39.138994', 'reading'),
      ('2016-12-24 21:012:56.159436', 'reading'))
select 
  *,
  activity_timestamp - (select max(activity_timestamp) from table1 as t1 where t2.activity_timestamp > t1.activity_timestamp) as diff
from table2 as t2 order by activity_timestamp, activity;
```

```
╔════════════════════════════╤══════════╤══════════╗
║     activity_timestamp     │ activity │   diff   ║
╠════════════════════════════╪══════════╪══════════╣
║ 2016-12-23 13:54:47.608561 │ reading  │ 00:01:00 ║
║ 2016-12-24 21:12:56.159436 │ reading  │ 00:03:00 ║
║ 2016-12-27 16:10:39.138994 │ reading  │ 00:04:00 ║
║ 2017-01-09 14:17:52.570397 │ reading  │ 00:02:00 ║
╚════════════════════════════╧══════════╧══════════╝
```

But I am not sure about the desired rows order...

Comment: when i was added condition for only record which is between last 20 min should be subtracted this query give me output in days

Comment: @AbhijeetGulve Use [`extract('epoch' from interval)` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to get the number of seconds. http://rextester.com/GZS98586

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use windowing functions:

```
with
  table1(activity_timestamp, activity) as (
    values
      ('2016-12-23 13:53:47.608561'::timestamp, 'details viewed'),
      ('2017-01-09 14:15:52.570397', 'details viewed'),
      ('2016-12-27 16:06:39.138994', 'details viewed'),
      ('2016-12-24 21:09:56.159436', 'details viewed')),
  table2(activity_timestamp, activity) as (
    values
      ('2016-12-23 13:54:47.608561'::timestamp, 'reading'),
      ('2017-01-09 14:17:52.570397', 'reading'),
      ('2016-12-27 16:10:39.138994', 'reading'),
      ('2016-12-24 21:012:56.159436', 'reading'))
   , lag AS (
select 
  *, lag(activity_timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY activity_timestamp)
from (
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION SELECT * FROM table2
) AS a

) SELECT *, lag - activity_timestamp
FROM lag
WHERE activity = 'reading'
ORDER BY 1
;
```

The results is :

```
    activity_timestamp     | activity |            lag             | ?column?  
----------------------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------
 2016-12-23 13:54:47.608561 | reading  | 2016-12-23 13:53:47.608561 | -00:01:00
 2016-12-24 21:12:56.159436 | reading  | 2016-12-24 21:09:56.159436 | -00:03:00
 2016-12-27 16:10:39.138994 | reading  | 2016-12-27 16:06:39.138994 | -00:04:00
 2017-01-09 14:17:52.570397 | reading  | 2017-01-09 14:15:52.570397 | -00:02:00
(4 rows)
```

To compare with other proposed version i create next script:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT '2016-01-01'::timestamp + '1 min'::interval * (random() * 10 + 1) AS activity_timestamp,
       'dv'::text AS activity
 FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT activity_timestamp + '1 min'::interval * (random()) AS activity_timestamp,
       'r'::text AS activity
  FROM table1;

CREATE INDEX i1 ON table1 (activity_timestamp DESC);
CREATE INDEX i2 ON table2 (activity_timestamp DESC);

-- Proposed by Abelisto
explain analyze
select 
  *,
  activity_timestamp - (select max(activity_timestamp)
                          from table1 as t1
                         where t2.activity_timestamp > t1.activity_timestamp
  ) as diff
from table2 as t2 order by activity_timestamp, activity;


-- Gordon Linoff - repaired    
explain analyze
select date_part('minutes', a.activity_timestamp - b.activity_timestamp), 
       a.activity_timestamp, b.activity_timestamp
from table1 a left join
     table2 b 
     on a.activity_timestamp < b.activity_timestamp + interval '20 minute' and
        a.activity_timestamp > b.activity_timestamp
order by b.activity_timestamp; 

-- My own version
explain analyze
WITH lag AS (
select 
  *, lag(activity_timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY activity_timestamp)
from (
    SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION SELECT * FROM table2
) AS a

) SELECT *, lag - activity_timestamp
FROM lag
WHERE activity = 'reading'
ORDER BY 1;
```

For query by Gordon the query time is too long (i do not want to wait).
Abelisto:

```
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=53399.41..53649.41 rows=100000 width=56) (actual time=944.918..957.470 rows=100000 loops=1)
   Sort Key: t2.activity_timestamp, t2.activity
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4104kB
   ->  Seq Scan on table2 t2  (cost=0.00..41675.09 rows=100000 width=56) (actual time=0.068..874.282 rows=100000 loops=1)
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Result  (cost=0.39..0.40 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=100000)
                 InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                   ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..0.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=100000)
                         ->  Index Only Scan using i1 on table1 t1  (cost=0.29..3195.63 rows=33167 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=100000)
                               Index Cond: ((activity_timestamp IS NOT NULL) AND (activity_timestamp < t2.activity_timestamp))
                               Heap Fetches: 100000
 Planning time: 0.392 ms
 Execution time: 961.594 ms
(13 rows)
```

My own:

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=39214.47..39216.97 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=325.461..325.461 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: lag.activity_timestamp
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   CTE lag
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=28162.14..34662.14 rows=200000 width=48) (actual time=131.906..265.747 rows=199982 loops=1)
           ->  Unique  (cost=28162.14..29662.14 rows=200000 width=40) (actual time=131.900..200.937 rows=199982 loops=1)
                 ->  Sort  (cost=28162.14..28662.14 rows=200000 width=40) (actual time=131.899..167.072 rows=200000 loops=1)
                       Sort Key: table1.activity_timestamp, table1.activity
                       Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4000kB
                       ->  Append  (cost=0.00..5082.00 rows=200000 width=40) (actual time=0.007..27.569 rows=200000 loops=1)
                             ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=40) (actual time=0.007..8.584 rows=100000 loops=1)
                             ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=40) (actual time=0.007..7.248 rows=100000 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on lag  (cost=0.00..4502.50 rows=1000 width=64) (actual time=325.458..325.458 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: (activity = 'reading'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 199982
 Planning time: 0.103 ms
 Execution time: 327.737 ms
(17 rows)
```

For compare I also run all queries for 1000 rows:
Abelisto:

```
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=469.71..472.21 rows=1000 width=56) (actual time=8.817..8.882 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Sort Key: t2.activity_timestamp, t2.activity
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 103kB
   ->  Seq Scan on table2 t2  (cost=0.00..419.89 rows=1000 width=56) (actual time=0.058..8.441 rows=1000 loops=1)
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Result  (cost=0.39..0.40 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1000)
                 InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                   ->  Limit  (cost=0.28..0.39 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1000)
                         ->  Index Only Scan using i1 on table1 t1  (cost=0.28..38.91 rows=332 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=1000)
                               Index Cond: ((activity_timestamp IS NOT NULL) AND (activity_timestamp < t2.activity_timestamp))
                               Heap Fetches: 1000
 Planning time: 0.311 ms
 Execution time: 8.948 ms
(13 rows)
```

Gordon:

```
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=21087.07..21364.85 rows=111111 width=24) (actual time=439.142..528.240 rows=452961 loops=1)
   Sort Key: b.activity_timestamp
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 15016kB
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.28..9493.05 rows=111111 width=24) (actual time=0.056..280.036 rows=452961 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on table1 a  (cost=0.00..16.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.114 rows=1000 loops=1)
         ->  Index Only Scan using i2 on table2 b  (cost=0.28..7.81 rows=111 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.171 rows=453 loops=1000)
               Index Cond: (activity_timestamp < a.activity_timestamp)
               Filter: (a.activity_timestamp < (activity_timestamp + '00:20:00'::interval))
               Heap Fetches: 452952
 Planning time: 0.102 ms
 Execution time: 545.139 ms
(11 rows)
```

My own:

```
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=291.85..291.87 rows=10 width=64) (actual time=2.942..2.942 rows=0 loops=1)
   Sort Key: lag.activity_timestamp
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   CTE lag
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=211.66..246.66 rows=2000 width=48) (actual time=1.504..2.374 rows=2000 loops=1)
           ->  Sort  (cost=211.66..216.66 rows=2000 width=40) (actual time=1.500..1.676 rows=2000 loops=1)
                 Sort Key: table1.activity_timestamp
                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 142kB
                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=62.00..82.00 rows=2000 width=40) (actual time=0.669..0.931 rows=2000 loops=1)
                       Group Key: table1.activity_timestamp, table1.activity
                       ->  Append  (cost=0.00..52.00 rows=2000 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.255 rows=2000 loops=1)
                             ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..16.00 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=0.007..0.073 rows=1000 loops=1)
                             ->  Seq Scan on table2  (cost=0.00..16.00 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=0.005..0.074 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on lag  (cost=0.00..45.02 rows=10 width=64) (actual time=2.939..2.939 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: (activity = 'reading'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2000
 Planning time: 0.092 ms
 Execution time: 3.001 ms
(18 rows)
```

Comment: Is my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Just use direct date comparisons in the `on` clause, rather than the minutes of the difference:

```
select date_part('minutes', a1.activity_timestamp - b.activity_timestamp), 
       a1.activity_timestamp, b.activity_timestamp
from table a1 left join
     table2 b 
     on a.active_timestamp < b.activity_timestamp + interval '20 minute' and
        a.activity_timetamp > b.activity_timestamp
order by b.activity_timestamp;
```

I should note:  If (in the case of multiple matches) you want to limit this to only one record from `a` or `b`, then you can use `distinct on`.  I'm not sure which table you want want only one record for, however.

Comment: I'm want to join on first table